# Como fazer para ter no máximo um líder selecionado em todos os selects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

Como faço para **quando eu selecionar a opção Líder**, o javascript **não permitir que seja selecionado uma outra função** (multiselect)?

O cenário é o seguinte: Cada select *representa as funções* de cada usuário.

O usuário que for selecionado como **Líder**, não pode ter mais nenhuma outra função; apenas a de Líder.

Se a opção for diferente de **Líder**, então o javascript permite selecionar mais de uma função.

Aqui está a minha tentativa:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var values = self.val();

    $("select").not(self).each(function() {
        var _values = $(this).val();
  if (_values == "1") {
    $(this).selectpicker('deselectAll')
   for (var v = _values.length; v--;) {
    if (values.indexOf(_values[v]) >= 0) {
     _values.splice(v, 1);
    }
   }

   $(this).val(_values);
  }
    });

 $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso que você quer:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var self = $(this);

    if($.inArray('1', self.val()) != -1) {
      self.find('[value!="1"]').prop('selected', false).prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      self.find('[value!="1"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  
    // Bloquear as opções líderes caso alguma seja selecionada
    var selectedValues = $.map($('select option:selected'), function(el) {
      return el.value;  
    });
    
    if($.inArray('1', selectedValues) != -1) {
      $('option[value="1"]:not(:selected)').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('option[value="1"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }

 $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value="1">Líder</option>
      <option value="10">Para Conhecimentor</option>
      <option value="11">Participante</option>
    </select>
```

**Explicação:**

O `select` será monitorado pelo evento `change`, então toda vez que tiver uma alteração no valor ele executará a função.

Na função eu obtenho os valores do `select` modificado, e verifico se algum desses valores é igual a 1, se sim eu procuro por todas as `options` desse `select` que são diferentes de 1 e tiro a propriedade `selected` e adiciono a `disabled`, se o valor 1 não tiver sido selecionado, eu habilito todas as `options` novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Mas teria como quando um select(pai) fosse selecionado como "Líder" e em outro select(filha) quando eu clicasse em "Líder" também, o javascript 'deselecionar' o  Líder do select(pai)? Você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: No caso só existiria no máximo um líder selecionado em todos os selects?

Comment: Exatamente isso

Comment: Acho que isso caberia melhor em uma nova pergunta, já que a pergunta inicial não detalha muito bem isso, edite a pergunta inicial ou crie uma nova para eu te ajudar.

Comment: Beleza, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Pergunta editada

Comment: Editei a resposta, vê se isso te ajuda!

Comment: Muito obrigado @JuniorNunes. O resultado era esse mesmo! Valeu!